# GeoJSON file Style property reading in Open Layers 3

Tags: css, gis, openlayers-3, geojson

I am trying to read style properties of individual features from a GeoJSON file and display same in Open Layers 3.
The GeoJSON appears to be valid but style is not being reflected in display.

How can we read individual style of each feature from GeoJSON file in Open Layers 3?

Thanks in advance

My GeoJSON file is as

```
  {"type": "FeatureCollection","crs": 
  { "type": "name", "properties": 
  { "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
  "features": [{ "type": "Feature","id": "abc","properties":{"name":"object1"},"geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates":[[17.0,67],[20.0,90.0]]},
  "style": 
  {
        "stroke" : "#ff0000",
       "stroke-width": "3"
  }
  }]}
```

Comment: Try maybe the solution suggested at [GeoJSON - how to style features of GeometryCollection](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165303/geojson-how-to-style-features-of-geometrycollection)

Comment: this approach defines style in code but i m looking for approach where style can be defined in geojson file itself like this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22474/geojson-styling-information

Comment: There's no way to OpenLayers read this style property from GeoJSON.